# Export a Grid in a xls file naming the sheets

Tags: export, grid-layouts

I try to export two grid in a same xls file, naming the sheets.
This is an exemplification of my issue, and it doesn't work.

```
m = Grid[Table[i - j, {i, 3}, {j, 4}]];
Export["m.xls", m]
```

it works correctly, but if I try this code, naming the sheet, it doesn't work

```
Export["m.xls", {"MySheet" -> m}]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `Grid` is the reason why it does not work!
Try this for multiple sheets

```
x = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];
y = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {5, 5}];
Export[$UserBaseDirectory <> "\\file.xlsx", {"Real" -> y,"Integer" -> y}]
```

In your case

```
m=Table[i - j, {i, 3}, {j, 4}];
Export[$UserBaseDirectory <> "\\file.xlsx","MySheet" -> m]
```

Comment: Minor error the y and y in the Export should have been x and y